# Two sections are on top of each other

Tags: javascript, html, css

The landing page and founders section are on top of each other. when I tried to add the founders section, it just messed up, here is the codepen URL you can check directly there.
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BeMyRx

I tried to make `position:absolute;` and `top:1500px;` but nothing happened

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
body,html{
    font-family: sans-serif;
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
flex-wrap:wrap;
position: center;
background-image:url(https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/508013798544769034/583722034157060096/Untitled-1.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;

}
.section-top{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.content{
    position: absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    transform: translate(-50% , -50%);
    text-align: center;
}
.content h1{
    color:#c0392b;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.content h3{
    color:white;
    font-size:15px;
    font-family: Arial;
}
.content a{
    background:#e74c3c;
    padding: 10px 24px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size:18px;
    border-radius:20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.testimonial-section{
    background: #3498db;
    padding: 40px 0;
  }

  .inner-width{
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0 20px;
  }

  .testimonial-section h1{
    text-align: center;
    color: #333;
    font-size: 24px;
  }

  .border{
    width: 100px;
    height: 3px;
    background: #333;
    margin: 40px auto;
  }

  .testimonial{
    background: #f1f1f1;
    padding: 40px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 8px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .test-info{
    display: flex;
    height: 60px;
    align-items: center;
  }

  .test-pic{
    width: 50px !important;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-right: 15px;
  }

  .test-name{
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #333;
  }

  .test-name span{
    display: block;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #3498db;
  }

  .testimonial p{
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 22px;
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
```

It's expected that the landing page should be on the top of the website, then the founders section should be next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the HTML code, you wrote "secton-top" instead of "section-top" in your class property.

Comment: and how please can i make the 4th box aline with the others

Comment: Questions to which the solution is "Correct a typo" aren't valuable to future readers, so generally we like to close them instead of answering/promoting them. In the future, instead of answering these questions, please submit a close vote and select the option: *Off Topic > Simple Typographical Error*.